# How to show a div relative to the position of a button on click of that button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$j(".btn-cart").on("click", function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            var top = $(this).offset().top;
            alert(top);
            $j("#content").animate({ 
            top: top
            }, 600);

        }
```

HTML:

for the div that is to be shown:

```
 <div id="angularJsApp" title="Basket" ng-app="cart" ng-controller="CartFormController">
        <div id="content" class="draggable" style="display:none;" ng-show="invoice.items.length > 0">
              <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"/>
              <label for="check">
              <div id="heads" >
                 <span id="commentBubble">
                   <a href=""><apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.CartStyleBundle,'Shopping-Cart-Button.png')}" alt="" /></a>
                 </span>
              </div>

              <article class="pane" id="user_1">

                <table class="table table-checkout">
                    <tr>

                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice.items">
                        <td>{{item.description}}</td>           
                        <td>{{item.qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.cost}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency : "£" }}</td>
                        <td>
                            [<a href="" ng-click="removeItem($index)" style="cursor: pointer;">X</a>]
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total:</td>
                        <td>{{total() | currency : "£" }}</td>

                    </tr> 
                </table>


            </article>

              </label>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

And HTML for the buttons:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="basketPanel" layout="none">                            
                        <a href="#content" class="btn-cart">
                            <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default btn-buy" onClick="microappscope().addItem('{!p.name}',{!p.Recommended_Retail_Price__c});" value="Add to Basket" id="btn" rerender="btn" action="{!addProductToCart}" >
                                <apex:param name="pId" value="{!p.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedProductId}"/>
                            </apex:commandButton>
                        </a>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
```

I want to show the div with id `#content` which is hidden by default on click of a button class `btn-cart`. And the div should open on top of the button. The problem is that I have many buttons in the page and on click of each of the button the same div will open relative to the position of the button that is being clicked.

See screenshot attached:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you're using `this` properly to get the button position. You just need to `show`, `slideDown`, or `fadeIn`. What's the question?

Comment: Yes I want to get the button position and show the #content div on top of the button when it is being clicked. But on running the code its showing the error "undefined is not a function"

Comment: At what line, exactly? That error often means that jQuery isn't loaded.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis. Maybe the error is in a later function because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the current position (relatve to the document) of the clicked button by using `.offset()`
and then change your div's offset according to that.

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var pos = $(this).offset();
    $('#toShow').show();
    $('#toShow').offset( pos );

});
```

Here is small example: http://jsfiddle.net/zje0uu9y/1/